# How to get the data after last | using instr and substr in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a column with data in two format

```
1.date|month|year
2.Date|year...
```

How to get the value after the last | ie year using InSTR and SuBstr in informatica

I have tried the logic but the data with three pipe is working file not with the data with two pipes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
SUBSTR( COL, INSTR(COL,'|',-1)+1)
```

INSTR will locate location of pipe form end of string. SUBSTR will pick data from that pipe till end of string.

Output -
[image]